# what is the fastest way to join several tables matching specific column values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 3 tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table_1 (
 id   INT(11),
 col1 TINYINT(1),
 col2 TINYINT(1),
 col3 TINYINT(1),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And so on for big_table_2 and big_table_3. The col1, col2, col3 values are either 0, 1 or null.

I'm looking for id's whose col1 value equals 1 in each table. I join them as follows, using the simplest method I can think of:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM big_table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN big_table_2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN big_table_3 AS t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.col1 = 1
AND t2.col1 = 1
AND t3.col1 = 1;
```

With 10 million rows per table, the query takes about 40 seconds to execute on my machine:

```
407231 rows in set (37.19 sec)
```

Explain results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref          | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL         | 10999387 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | testDB.t3.id |        1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | testDB.t3.id |        1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
```

If I declare index on col1, the result is slightly slower:

```
407231 rows in set (40.84 sec)
```

I have also tried the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM (SELECT distinct ta1.id FROM big_table_1 ta1 WHERE ta1.col1=1) as t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ta2.id FROM big_table_2 ta2 WHERE ta2.col1=1 AND ta2.id = t1.id)
AND EXISTS (SELECT ta3.id FROM big_table_3 ta3 WHERE ta3.col1=1 AND ta3.id = t1.id);
```

But it's slower:

```
407231 rows in set (44.01 sec) [with index on col1]
407231 rows in set (1 min 36.52 sec) [without index on col1]
```

Is the aforementioned simple method basically the fastest way to do this in MySQL? Would it be necessary to shard the table onto multiple servers in order to get the result faster?

Addendum: EXPLAIN results for Andrew's code as requested (I trimmed the tables down to 1 million rows only, and the index is on id and col1):

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>  | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  332814 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>  | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  333237 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |  333505 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  4 | DERIVED     | big_table_3 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL | 1000932 | Using where; Using index       |
|  3 | DERIVED     | big_table_2 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL | 1000507 | Using where; Using index       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | big_table_1 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL | 1000932 | Using where; Using index       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kicks try it with a covered index (a composite of id,col1)
So 1 index make it primary composite. No other indexes.

Then run `analyze table` xxx (3 times total, once per table)

Then fire it off hoping the mysql cbo isnt to dense to figure it out.

Second idea is to see results without a where clause. Convert it all inside of join on clause

Comment: The result is about 4 times faster with the covered index, nice. It'll be a problem if I have more cols and constantly choose different ones though. Converting to join only has about the same speed as using 'where'.

Comment: Thx for letting us know

Comment: If u can endure a slightly slower insert, or update (on colN columns), AND this is a freq need worth it in the face of "new data" slower ... then a few covered indexes on very narrow (size) column composites will keep engine from having to go to data pages as all info is covered in index. If needed use `force index` if mysql cbo has brain fart

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN` (same as `JOIN`) lets the optimizer pick whether to use the table to its left or the table to its right.  The simplified `SELECT` you presented could start with any of the three tables.

The optimizer likes to start with the table with the `WHERE` clause.  Your simplified example implies that each table is equally good *IF* there is an `INDEX` *starting with* `col1`.  (See retraction below.)

The *second* and subsequent tables need a different rule for indexing.  In your simplified example, `col1` is used for filtering and `id` is used for `JOINing`.  `INDEX(col1, id)` and `INDEX(id, col1)` work equally well for getting to the second table.

I keep saying "your simplified example" because as soon as you change anything, most of the advice in these answers is up for grabs.

(The retraction) When you have a column with "low cardinality" such as your `col%`, with only 0,1,NULL possibilities, `INDEX(col1)` is essentially useless since it it faster to blindly scan the table rather than use the index.

On the other hand, `INDEX(col1, ...)` may be useful, as mentioned for the second table.

However neither is useful for the *first* table.  If you have such an `INDEX`, it will be ignored.

Then comes "covering".  Again, your example is unrealistically simplistic because there are essentially no fields touched other than `id` and `col1`.  A "covering" index includes *all* the fields of a table that are touched in the query.  A covering index is virtually always smaller than the data, so it takes less effort to run through a covering index, hence faster.

(Retract the retraction)  `INDEX(col1, id)`, in *that* order is a useful covering index for the *first* table.

Imagine how my discussion had gone if you had not mentioned that col1 had only 3 values.  Quite different.

And we have not gotten to `ORDER BY`, `IN(...)`, `BETWEEN...AND...`, engine differences, tricks with the `PRIMARY KEY`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc.

[More insight into building indexes from Selects](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

`ANALYZE TABLE` should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM 
(SELECT id from big_table_1 where col1 = 1) AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id from  big_table_2 where col1 = 1)  AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT id from  big_table_3 where col1 = 1)  AS t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
```

Comment: It ran for a few minutes without a result, so I cancelled it.

Comment: This is not helpful because it needs to create a subquery.

Comment: yes, but sub query fetches only ID's; this should be faster if there are hundreds of columns... I am wondering what the Query plan sais.